# Running several latex processes in parallel

Tags: compiling, automation, texmf

I am working on an experiment running LaTeX on server to compile some documents on the fly. Assuming I want to have several workers waiting for documents to be compiled, are there any access issues in running several `latex` / `lualatex` processes in parallel? Should I for example duplicate the `texmf-var` directory for each process to avoid issues when generating `ls-R` or font files in parallel?

Comment: No, you are free to parallelise as much as you like for regular compiles. Fonts and ls could pose problems. Do you really need to create fonts in parallel?

Comment: @zeroth Your statement seem quite contradictory: can I parallelize as much as I like, or will fonts and `ls-R` files pose problems? It's not about me "needing" to create fonts in parallel, but my worry is about 2 documents being compiled in parallel and each of the processes calling `mktexpk` for instance. Has anyone experience trying this?

Comment: I am talking about _regular_ compiles, as in document processing, sorry if that was unclear. About the others I have no real experience, however I wonder why you can't have the fonts and packages already installed? It seems like the server would have much work to do, if it should be computed each time? (I am guessing you are cleaning up afterwards to limit footprint of installation, or something similar?)

Comment: @zeroth FYI, _regular_ compiles call `mktexpk` whenever a MetaFont or Type1 font is used for the first time; it's part of the standard latex routine for document processing... Your TeX distribution most probably contains a folder called `texmf-var` where TeX engines store their run-time caches. Conflicts in that folder with several processes running in parallel is what I worry about.

Comment: How much do you know about the documents you're processing? Duplicating `texmf-var` could also mean duplicating the computational effort spent on generating fonts and such, eating up some of the gain from parallelizing. If you know what fonts etc. will be needed, these should be pre-generated before the parallel processing begins. Furthermore, there will be a "closure" for all stuff which can be auto-generated in a given TeX installation. Maybe you should just generate everything on the system you'd like to parallelize on.

Comment: @Stephan Pre-generating all the potential fonts is unfortunately not a (desirable) option , as I wish to have as many font families as possible and the number of possible sizes is quite large... I am just wondering if `texmf-var` and commands such as `mktexpk` are robust to concurrent runs. I guess I'll have to create some script to try it out :)

Comment: In case they aren't, you could still write wrappers that use some kind of mutex to block until a particular run completed.

Comment: @Xavier Do you really need to generate `pk` fonts? That seems quite archaic to me. Pre-generating all neccessary `tfm` files seems feasible unless you're using `microtype` with `dvi` or somesuch. I am almost certain things will go wrong when two `mktex...` processes meet. They generate their files in the user directories on multi-user systems, so conflicts between different users are not an issue.

Comment: @Stephan Some `pk` fonts get generated automatically, mostly for maths (e.g. with automatic adjustment of the size of symbols) :(

Comment: @Xavier This is strange. There are some `pk` fonts in the TeXLive distro, but I don't have a single one which was auto-generated here on my system. So maybe if you're not actually using `pk` fonts, you should try to understand why your sytsem is generating them. Avoiding unneccessary auto-generation seems to be a key to parallelising to me.

Comment: Normally `$VARTEXFONTS` points to `$TEXMFVAR/fonts` and `$TEXMFVAR` is *not* subject to `ls-R` caching. The chances of two instances of `mktexpk` or `mktextfm` trying to generate the same fonts are small; a problem *might* arise if one instance of `pdftex` is trying to load a font file precisely when a `mktexpk` process is overwriting a file just generated by another instance. However, most fonts are Type1, nowadays; only `tfm` files for CMCyrillic are commonly generated at runtime.

Comment: Maybe this project could be interesting:
https://github.com/scribtex/clsi

Answer (score 4):

before I send a manuscript of a book to my publisher for printing 
I create the example files in a last run *all* new to be sure that everything is ok. I *always* use paralell LateX processing for this. 
I work under Linux and can run up to 10 runs parallel 0...9. This saves a lot of time because I have sometimes more than 1000 examples. Every example is created from within LaTeX as an external file. The file extension defines the type of the example, eg .tex, .ltx, pltx, and so on. Depending to the used processor type (number of kernels) a shell script starts all processes.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I am just worried that in your case, you are reprocessing documents, hence all the fonts should already have been generated. In my case, I want to build a sort of online compiler, and can't presume what will be generated...